# How to setup $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ to allow for propagation of electromagnetic wavepacket?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

When the two wave fields of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are given a priori, then the coupled equations

$$ \frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t} = curl (\vec E)$$

$$ \frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t} = - curl (\vec B)$$

completely determine the time evolution of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ (where c=1, $\mu_0$=1, and j=0).

My questions are:

1. What is the standard "particle in a box" first test case problem for electromagnetic waves?
2. How to setup the initial $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ wave field at t=0 to allow for the propagation of an electromagnetic wavepacket / light?

Comment: You mean in vacuum, right? Otherwise, you would have a source term in one of your equations...

Comment: Do you have an electromagnetism textbook to which you can refer? If not, I would suggest the one by Griffiths as a good undergraduate introduction.

Comment: @hft the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ field by themselves are enough to completely specify their electromagnetic cross interaction, don't they? If there are sources present, they could have been internalized a priori into the initial distribution within the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ field?

Comment: Not generally... If there are sources present then there is a $J$ term in your second equation. But often we are interested in wave propagation through vacuum or a homogeneous medium where we can account for some effects, like polarization for example, via a linear dielectric function.

Comment: anyways, to proceed in vacuum, you can take the partial time derivative of your first equation and then plug in your second equation to get a wave equation. But... this is all textbook stuff, so it would be good to just crack a textbook...

Comment: @hft thank you. i see the standard textbook wave equation is already the correct initial condition?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the identity $\nabla\times(\nabla\times f) = -\nabla^2 f + \nabla \cdot (\nabla\cdot f)$ and the fact that $\nabla\cdot B = 0$.

Then you arrive at the wave equation for the electric and magnetic field:
$$\nabla^2 E - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E = 0$$

1. The easiest solution to this equation (which you call "particle in a box for electromagnetism", although I think this is more the analog to the free particle solution ;))
   $$E(r,t) = E_0 e^{ik\cdot r}.$$
2. An illustrative example I think is a gaussian wavepacket that travels in z-direction with initial condition
   $$E(z,t=0) = e^{-z^2} e^{ikz}$$

In vacuum it will propagate with the group velocity $v=c=1$:

$$E(z,t) = e^{-(z-vt)^2} e^{ikz - i\omega t}.$$

Without dispersion it will always be the same gaussian wave packet, just translated in z-direction by $vt$.

You can find the corresponding magnetic field using Maxwell's equations.

Comment: thank you vm! i am a little unclear about the complex exponential $\exp(ikz)$ in the solution. In electromagnetism, $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are real valued, right? What components does the i separate?

Comment: Yes, they are real-valued. Since the equations governing electromagnetism are linear, we can calculate them using complex-valued functions, which makes many things easier, and then taking either the real or the imaginary part of the formal solution to be the "real" solution. I just wonder, when you are already talking about particle in a box and stuff, shouldn't you then be familiar with basic electromagnetism? Anyway, as others pointed out, the first two chapters of a standard EM textbook should answer your questions.

Comment: i will make sure to look it up. There are apparently a few solutions given in a lecture by feynman: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_20.html